How to compare mediation models with one or two mediators?
I'm looking to compare the indirect effect sizes of two models:
IV1 -> IV2 -> DV
and
IV1 -> IV2 -> IV3 -> DV
Is there a way to do this in R?
I know how to run the first model using the mediation package. But I'm not sure how to have multiple mediators.

You can easily do that with the package lavaan. Here are the steps :

you create the second mediation model;
you fix the mediator 2's parameters to 0;
you run both models;
you can compare them with the anova() function.

Here is an example with an hypothetical data set.
# A simple data set
set.seed(42)
jd <- MASS::mvrnorm(120,
                    mu = rep(0, 5),
                    Sigma = matrix(c(  1, .5,-.2,-.1,
                                      .5,  1,-.4,-.2,
                                     -.2,-.4,  1, .5,
                                     -.1,-.2, .5,  1,), 
                                   4, 4),
                    empirical = TRUE)
colnames(jd) <- c("X","M1","M2","Y")
jd <- as.data.frame(jd)

# The two models
# 1) The second model
model2 <- ' # direct effect
             Y ~  c * X
            # mediator1
             M1 ~ a * X
             Y  ~ b * M1
            # mediator2
             M2 ~ d * X 
             M2 ~ e * M1
             Y  ~ f * M2
            # indirect effects
             ab  := a * b
             df  := d * f
             aef := a * e * f
            # total effect
             total := c + (a*b + d*f + a*e*f)
         '
# 2) Fix parameters to 0
model1 <- ' # direct effect
             Y ~  c * X
            # mediator1
             M1 ~ a * X
             Y  ~ b * M1
            # mediator2
             M2 ~ 0 * X 
             M2 ~ 0 * M1
             Y  ~ 0 * M2
            # indirect effects
             ab  := a * b
            # total effect
             total := c + (a*b)
         '
# 3) Carry both models
library(lavaan)
mod1 <- sem(model = model1, data = jd)
mod2 <- sem(model = model2, data = jd)
# summary(mod1)
# summary(mod2)

# 4) Compare
anova(mod2, mod1)

The output :
Chi-Squared Difference Test

     Df    AIC     BIC  Chisq Chisq diff   RMSEA Df diff Pr(>Chisq)    
mod2  0 946.66  971.74  0.000                                          
mod1  3 991.20 1007.93 50.546     50.546 0.36342       3  6.114e-11 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

The Pr(>Chisq) column tells you that the model are significantly different and the one with the lower AIC is the best.
Make sure you have the same variables and a different number of free parameters, i.e., why we added the second mediator in the simple mediation model.
